# How to get Bitmap/SKBitmap from Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have an image in my Android project Resource/Drawable folder. I want to draw this image to a SKCanvas. Here's the code I have so far:

```
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("no_image.jpg");
SKBitmap currentBitmap = imageSource as SKBitmapImageSource;
```

However, currentBitmap is always null. The imageSource is not null, so the file is being correctly located. I tried casting imageSource to Bitmap and SKBitmap, but get the compiler error "Cannot convert type Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource to SkiaSharp.SKBitmap". Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: var img = SKBitmap.Decode("no_image.jpg");

Comment: This causes a crash with the following error: "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xe in tid 10753"

Comment: Were you ever able to do this